# Add class to every parent with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am building menu with jquery, and I have set active class to selected element but I want to give active class to every parent element, can that be done

```
<ul class="cdrvo" id="nav">
        <li class="nod1" id="1"><a class=" " href="items.aspx?itemID=1">Ljevi Meni</a>
            <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" >
                <li class="nod3" id="3"><a class=" " href="items.aspx?itemID=3">3</a>
                    <ul style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" >
                        <li class="nod12 active" id="12"><a class=" " href="items.aspx?itemID=12">12</a></li>
                        <li class="nod13" id="13"><a class=" " href="items.aspx?itemID=13">13</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nod6" id="6"><a class=" " href="items.aspx?itemID=6">6</a></li>                    
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element.parents().addClass('active');
```

This will add the `active` class to **ALL** the elements parents (including `body`).
You can filter the parents with selectors that suits your needs :

```
element.parents('ul').addClass('active');
```

Comment: tnx, seckond one worked like charm, I was trying with parent() but parents() did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could use [parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) and stop at the body:

```
$('#yourelement').hover(function(){
    $(this).parentsUntil('#nav').addClass('active');
},
function(){
    $(this).parentsUntil('#nav').removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the `.parents` selector http://api.jquery.com/parents/

$(document).ready(function(){$("li.active").parents().addClass("active");});

http://jsfiddle.net/n4tuw/